# Get class method arguments type

Tags: php, oop

I'm reading about the php `ReflectionFunction`.Is it possible to use it to check the type of the various arguments of a class method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [`ReflectionMethod`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php) class instead of `ReflectionFunction`:

```
class Test {
    public function Test1(int $number, string $str) {  }
}

//get the information about a specific method.
$rm = new ReflectionMethod('Test', 'Test1');

//get all parameter names and parameter types of the method.
foreach ($rm->getParameters() as $parameter) {
    echo 'Name: '.$parameter->getName().' - Type: '.$parameter->getType()."\n";
}
```

**demo:** https://ideone.com/uBUghi

---

You can use the following solution to get all parameters of all methods, using [`ReflectionClass`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php):

```
class Test {
    public function Test1(int $number, string $str) {  }
    public function Test2(bool $boolean) {  }
    public function Test3($value) {  }
}

//get the information of the class.
$rf = new ReflectionClass('Test');

//run through all methods.
foreach ($rf->getMethods() as $method) {
    echo $method->name."\n";

    //run through all parameters of the method.
    foreach ($method->getParameters() as $parameter) {
        echo "\t".'Name: '.$parameter->getName().' - Type: '.$parameter->getType()."\n";
    }
}
```

**demo:** https://ideone.com/Ac7M2L

Comment: I will try, tanks for the suggestion.